# Validating Firebase user on existing WebApi rest service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to try to implement user validation on a .Net WebApi rest service that i currently have build.  I have two mobile apps build that communicate with the rest service. Implementing Firebase Auth (facebook, google) is relatively straight forward on the mobile side. How ever I am having trouble figuring out the best way to validate that user on my WebApi.  The process that I thought I could take would be:

1. Client login on mobile retrieve token from Firebase
2. Existing WebApi validate token against Firebase
3. Allow access to Rest services

I have looked at the RestSharp libraries as well as the .net library for generating a firebase token.  Is there a endpoint i can hit to grab users or check if a user is valid?

EDIT

I was going down the path of using a JWT token.  Questions with this, what do I encrypt. And what endpoint do I try to query the user.

`var tokenGenerator = new Firebase.TokenGenerator(secretKey);
            var authPayload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
              { "uid", "9ioA6m........3m1EG93" },
              { "provider", "facebook" },
              { "data", "here" }
            };
            string token = tokenGenerator.CreateToken(authPayload);`

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use the [JWT C# library][1]. And use the Realtime Database Secret to mint the token and then use the REST API. [1]: https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt

Comment: @DavidEast - Thanks for the reply.  Do you know what end point on the REST API i would want to hit to check users?  I was going down the path of using JWT, there is a library called FirebaseTokenGenerator.

Comment: @DavidEast - Ok, i think i see my problem.  It looks like if you want to query the Users, you have to first add them to the database, doesnt look like there is a way to hit the authenticated users directly through the REST API  (Feature Request) :)  I was able to generate a JWT and hit the database, looks like this will have to be my best option.   - Thanks